# How do I convert id type to CGPoint type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array of CGPoints. When I extract the stored elements of this array, I want it in the CGPoint type not id. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Show the code for how the array was created.

Comment: You cannot store CGPoint in the array. Do you mean NSValue? Can you show the code where you add cgpoint to the array?

Comment: [colEndPoint addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point2]];

Comment: This is the code :

for (int i =0;colEndPoint.count; i++)
    {
        [self lineTo:[colEndPoint objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

- (void *)lineTo:(CGPoint)p1 
{
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like...

```
CGPoint yourPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);

NSValue *pointValueObject = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:yourPoint];

[myMutableArray addObject:pointValueObject];

NSValue *objectFromArray = [myMutableArray lastObject];

CGPoint pointFromArray = [objectFromArray CGPointValue];
```

This will store the `CGPoint` into a mutable array and pull it out again converting it back into a `CGPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a simple cast.

```
CGPoint point = [yourArray[1] CGPointValue];
```

Comment: Yes, it is in the form of NSvalue on storing in the array.